# Graphql bad request due escaped qoutes using spring boot RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

Using **postman** everything is **fine** with raw JSON content type.

```
{"query":"{getX(filter: \"X\", filter2: \"Y\") {data1, data2, data3} }
```

When invoking in the java **client** and I get **400 error**.

```
String body = "{\"query\":\"{getX(filter: \\\"X\\\", filter2: \\\"Y\\\") {data1, data2, data3}}\"}"; 
// simply copied from postman to Intellij and it did some escaping for me
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
ResponseEntity<List<SomeObject>> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, POST, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SomeObject>>(){});
```

On **server side** I can see that I'm getting error:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of 'java.util.LinkedHashMap': no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ....
//Looks like server thinks I passed one big string
... payload="{\"query\":\"{getX(filter: \\\"X\\\", filter2: \\\"Y\\\") {data1, data2, data3}}\"}" ...
```

But on **server side** when I'm invoking from **postman** I'm getting this **payload log** which works just fine

```
... payload={"query":"{getX(filter: \"X\", filter2: \"Y\") {data1, data2, data3}}"} ...
```

Obviously I can see that when I'm invoking from java payload data is ***wrapped inside qoutes*** and every qoute is escaped inside it, meanwhile from postman payload is not wrapped under qoutes and nothing is escaped except filters. What solution exactly could I do, using **restTemplate**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, basically all I needed is to put "query" as a key in a map and else in the value. In this case body does not get weirdly wrapped in qoutes.

```
Map<String, String> body = of("query", "{getX(filter: \"X\", filter2: \"Y\") {data1, data2, data3}}");
HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
//and pass it to restTemplate...
```

Answer (score 1):

I will highly recommend to use variables for passing query parameters as show in [GraphQL docs](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/), and also will recommend [insomnia](https://support.insomnia.rest/article/176-graphql-queries) as client for GraphQL queries since it has support for GraphQL with nice ui representation, probably below will be your request with variables

```
{
   "query":"query($filter_1: string, $filter_2 : string){getX(filter: $filter_1, filter2: $filter_2) {data1, data2, data3} }",
   "variables" : {"filter_1":"X", "filter_2": "Y"}
}
```

You have to pass all the above payload ad POST body in request

Comment: Honestly I doubt that this would fix the issue I'm having at the moment. Did not try it yet, but I think I'd get exactly same results just also variables would be wrapped inside the quotation marks. As you can see, previously entire json request, looks like, got wrapped inside one big string

Comment: variables is a JSON so you don't need ant quotes to encode, i usually implement GraphQL call in this way, The attached insomnai link has very good example